# Can a property card ever end up in the bank?

Tags: monopoly-deal

In the Monopoly Deal card game, in addition to money cards or action cards, can I use a *property* card as money to my bank? Or do property cards always get played in their own area?

If another player charges rent and I have to give her a property card, can she use that as a property card or does it go to her bank?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Guessing the original meaning when it isn't clear is perilous. It should be left to the original poster to edit and clarify.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson I play the card game so I believe I understand what was originally intended; the OP believes (mistakenly) that a player can play a property card into their bank pile, like they can with an action card. If you could, then his question about what happens when the property goes to another player as payment makes sense. Since you actually can't, then that follow-up is moot. But that belongs in an answer, not in a comment :). I stand by my edit and no, we don't normally restrict clarifying edits to the OP.

Comment: @BradC, We don't restrict editing for clarity, obviously, but editing to change the meaning of the post (the game, the mechanism, the basis and point of the question, etc.) is best left to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

**No, property can never end up in the bank.**

[According to the printed rules](http://monopolydealrules.com/index.php?page=instructionbook#top), you can only play money and/or action cards into your bank, property always goes on the table in your "property collection":

> 2. **PLAY UP TO 3 CARDS** from your hand, onto the table in front of you. You don't have to play any cards if you don't want to. Play your 3 cards in any combination of the following: A, B, and/or C, in any order:
>
> (A) Put money/action cards into your own bank
>
> - Players can charge each other for rent, birthdays etc. **Build up a 'Bank' pile in front of you, using Money cards and/or Action cards**.
>
> (B) Put down properties into your own collection
>
> - **Lay Property cards down in front of you to build up your Property sets**.
>
> (C) Play action cards into the center

So what about when property is used to pay rent to another player? Further down is the relevant rule:

> IMPORTANT! HOW TO PAY OTHER PLAYERS
>
> - (4 other rules)
> - **If you pay with property cards, they must go into the other player's property collection**.

So the situation you describe, where you are paying rent *using property from your bank* can never arise. Property can be used to pay rent, but moves from your property collection to your opponent's.